# What is the difference between this and (this)?

Tags: java, recursion, intellij-idea

```
public class classA implements interfaceA {

  @Override
  public Optional<T> methodA(String s) {
    return (this).methodA(s); // <-  IDEA doesn't underlines as recursion
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<T> methodB(String s) {
    return (this).methodB(s); // <- IDEA doesn't underlines as recursion
  }
```

```
public class classA implements interfaceA {

  @Override
  public Optional<T> methodA(String s) {
    return this.methodA(s);  // <-  IDEA underlines as recursion
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<T> methodB(String s) {
    return this.methodB(s); // <- IDEA underlines as recursion
  }
```

I have't seen (this) in such a form. Can anyone link reference to documentation or explain what is the difference between usual form and in parentheses?

Comment: The different is same as the difference between `1 + 3` and `(1 + 3)`

Comment: Nit: `()` are parentheses, not curly braces `{}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no difference whatsoever. Those braces are not needed in your example and should be removed.

Apparently it also trips up IntelliJ's recursion detection. That's just a minor bug in that feature, not an indication that the code works differently.

Comment: Yeah probably a regex that is not complete enough

Comment: I doubt that it uses something so simple as a regex (since it'll warn on a recursive call even if it doesn't mention `this` at all). More likely, the braces make it so the internal representation goes from `definitely a this reference` to `some expression I don't even know`. Either way, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

From [the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5):

> A parenthesized expression is a primary expression whose type is the type of the contained expression and whose value at run time is the value of the contained expression. If the contained expression denotes a variable then the parenthesized expression also denotes that variable.

Since `this` is the contained expression, `(this)` has the same type and value as `this`.

However, `this` is not a variable, so the last part does not apply (you can't write `(this) = ...` or `this = ...`, but you can write `(a) = ...` as an equivalent to `a = ...`).

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between these two.